# Can a sequence of functions converge to a discontinuous limit under norm?

Tags: metric-spaces

I'm a bit confused about how to take the distance between two functions where one function is discontinuous. Supposing we have the $L^1$ metric $d_1$ and $f_n(x) = x^n$ defined over $[0, 1]$. $x^n$ has discontinuous limit function so how would one take the distance under $d_1$?

Would it look like ($x=1$):
$$d_1(x^n, 1) = \int_1^1 |x^n - 1|dx$$ and for $0\le x \lt1$
$$d_1(x^n, 0) = \int_0^1 |x^n - 0|dx$$? Thanks, I'm just a little unsure. I want to find out whether $f_n$ converges to its pointwise limit under $d_1$.

Comment: What is the underlying space here?

Comment: C[0,1] real-valued.

Comment: The sequence converges to $0$ in the $L^1$-norm. $L^p$-convergence does not imply pointwise convergence.

Comment: I'm still not sure. I find the pointwise limit first and then need to check whether it converges to its pointwise limit under $L^1$ - norm - so how do I check that?

Answer (score 1):

In general, converges in the $L^p$ norm for $p < \infty$ does not imply pointwise convergence of the sequence - at best, it implies pointwise a.e. convergence of a subsequence.

The limit function here is the zero function: We have
$$d_1(x^n, 0) = \int_0^1 x^n dx = \frac{1}{n + 1} \to 0$$
as $n \to \infty$, implying that $x^n \to 0$ in the $d_1$ metric.

---

It's worth pointing out that the pointwise limit, which is $0$ for $x \in [0,1)$ and $1$ at $x = 1$, is equal to the zero function almost everywhere. So in the Lebesgue space $L^1$, we would identify these two functions as equal.

Comment: I understand your answer. The problem is I'm studying a general topology course and we're only interested in the metrics coming from $L^1$ - we don't learn about these spaces. So the question asks me to find the pointwise limit and then check whether the sequence converges to its pointwise limit under the $L^1$ metric. That is, I'm not too sure how to approach my question since it first asks to find the pointwise limit?

Comment: The pointwise limit of the sequence isn't an element of the underlying space (since it's not continuous), so it doesn't make sense to talk about it in the given metric.

Comment: So then would we say that it doesn't converge to its pointwise limit in $L^1$ or that this question doesn't make sense?

Comment: It doesn't have a pointwise limit in the given space ($C[0,1]$; in the larger space $L^1$, it does), but the sequence is convergent in the given metric $d_1$.

Comment: Haha I appreciate your comments - but it doesn't clear the confusion. The question as given to me asks: "Find the pointwise limit $f$ of $f_n$ and investigate if $f_n$ converges to $f$ with respect to the $L^1$-metric." So what's the answer? :P

Comment: @McT The pointwise limit is the discontinuous function you found, and it's easy to check that $\int |x^n - f| \to 0$, where $f$ is the discontinuous pointwise limit. My answer was based on the comment that you're restricting your attention to $C[0,1]$.

Comment: I don't doubt your answer :) We are restricting ourselves to C[0,1]. Also could you tell me how it's easy to check that?

Comment: You can just compute the integral directly; it's equal to $1 / (n + 1)$.

Comment: :( but the whole reason I'm confused is that the limit function is discontinuous so I don't see how we can pick f = 0 when f isn't 0 everywhere :(